# Is the fetchAssetCollections method deprecated in latest version of Photos library?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode10, xcode10.3

I created a command line project in XCode

[image]

I think this is a valid code in swift

```
 let all = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .smartAlbumUserLibrary,
```

However when I try it now, the autocomplete does not list  `fetchAssetCollections` as an option.

[image]

Similar issue in my constructor

[image]

Here is the code fragment

```
import Foundation
import Photos

class PhotoExplorer {

    init() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register(self)
    }

    func listAssetsInPhoto() -> PHCollection {
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        PHAssetCollection.fetch //  <- To be complete

    }
}
```

Here is my build settings

[image]

I added `import PhotosUI` but it does not help.

Did I do something wrong? Is there an API change?

Comment: Just tried on my side and it should work just fine, it is a `class` function thats ok. It seems to be a completion problem only Have you tried to restart XCode?

Comment: I have restarted xcode. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to fix it is by recreating the project.